# Limit of $h(x)= \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$

Tags: functions

If both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$  make :

$$\lim\limits_{x \to 1} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}= 1 $$

and the serieses $$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_n= 1$$ $$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}  b_n =1  $$

$$\implies \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(a_n)}{g(b_n)}= 1  $$

Why this is not true? 
isn't this true by Heine rule?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not true, because your first statement says nothing about $f(x)/g(y)$ when $x \ne y$.  For example, you might have 
$g(a_n) = f(a_n)$ but $g(b_n) = 2 f(a_n)$.

Answer (score 4):

Try with $f(x)=g(x)=x-1$ and $a_n=1+\frac{1}{n}$ and $b_n=1+\frac{1}{n^2}$

Comment: I edited to a continuous function to make it obvious that it doesn't hold either for continus $f$ and $g$

Comment: but what is missing in the Heine rule conditions that it doesnt hold?

Comment: @SijaanHallak, what is the Heine rule ? Never heard of it.